# Any event for when a notification fires in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uilocalnotification, localnotification

Is there a way to execute a process when a local notification is fired? I know about the `didReceiveLocalNotification` event in the `AppDelegate`, but this only happens when the user actually clicks on the notification. When a notification is fired though, that's where I'd like to do something. Is there a place for that?

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't believe your app will be launched unless the user responds to the notification.